# Why is SBT in IntelliJ accessing Maven over the Internet in spite of me configuring local nexus for it?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have the following repositories in my build.sbt

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Maven Central" at "http://10.1.1.200:8080/nexus/content/repositories/central/",
    "Typesafe Repository" at "http://10.1.1.200:8080/nexus/content/repositories/typesafe/",
    "Atlassian Releases" at "http://10.1.1.200:8080/nexus/content/repositories/atlassian/",
    "scalaz-bintray" at "http://10.1.1.200:8080/nexus/content/repositories/scalaz-bintray/",
    "Sonatype Releases" at "http://10.1.1.200:8080/nexus/content/repositories/sonatype/"
  )
```

But when I run my Play project IntelliJ Idea still hits the Maven repository over the Internet. And when that times out it seems to hit the local repository.

How can I configure it to hit the local Nexus repository first?

Answer (score 4):

You should change your SBT settings as to below to use custom repositories

You need to

> create a local file with name as "repositories" and with content in the below format (modify URL pattern to match yours)
>
> [repositories]
>   local
>   my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://repo.company.com/ivy-releases/,[organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]
>   my-maven-proxy-releases: http://repo.company.com/maven-releases/

then, use the below config

> -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config= .... rest of the parameters

Follow the below to make the changes

> Go to settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) -> Other Settings -> SBT -> Add the
>   above parameters to existing VM parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should be using proxy repositories, instead of changing build.sbt file (as other people might want to use the same build.sbt file but don't have access to your local repositories)

Documentation is [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html#Proxy+Repositories). If you want to completely not hit external repos, you can add -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true whose documentation is on the same page.

Comment: If I use standalone installation of SBT the location for repositories file is ~/.sbt/repositories.Where is the location for the same file for IntelliJ SBT jar?

Comment: Should use the same location, if not you can manually point it by using sbt.repository.config  http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Command+Line+Options